# What is the difference between twentythirteen_paging_nav() and get_adjacent_post() function in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I just want to know that what is the differences between **twentythirteen_paging_nav()** and

**get_adjacent_post()** function in wordpress. Although both works to go next or previous post

yet some differences must be between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_adjacent_post()` returns a post object, based on the provided arguments -- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_adjacent_post

`twentythirteen_paging_nav()` is a part of the twentythirteen theme, it is not a part of the WordPress core and (as you probably guessed from the name) generates a pagination using `next_posts_link()` and `previous_posts_link()` and prints additional HTML as well. 
The function can be found in the functions.php of the twentythirteen theme:

```
function twentythirteen_paging_nav() {
    global $wp_query;

    // Don't print empty markup if there's only one page.
    if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages < 2 )
        return;
    ?>
    <nav class="navigation paging-navigation" role="navigation">
        <h1 class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Posts navigation', 'twentythirteen' ); ?></h1>
        <div class="nav-links">

            <?php if ( get_next_posts_link() ) : ?>
            <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older posts', 'twentythirteen' ) ); ?></div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ( get_previous_posts_link() ) : ?>
            <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentythirteen' ) ); ?></div>
            <?php endif; ?>

        </div><!-- .nav-links -->
    </nav><!-- .navigation -->
    <?php
}
```

Comment: For a second I thought Wordpress was versioning their functions :(